# tiled background image looks darker than original on xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've followed the following tutorial : http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/03/08/ios-101-pattern-images/

and I tried to add a tiled background image to my app, I used the following code:

```
UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fabric.png"];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
```

But somehow when I run the app the background image appears much darker than the original image. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I was wondering why is that happening and how can I fix it.

thanks

Comment: can you upload your `fabric.png`?

Comment: If I could I would give you a "correct answer" :)

the image itself was transparent, when I uploaded it to another site I could see the problem laid in the image itself.

Comment: have you uploaded fabric.png? or screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

the image itself was transparent, when I uploaded it to another site I could see the problem laid in the image itself.